# Need an SQL statement that can produce results from one table with two columns in another table

Tags: sql

Here is my question.

I have two tables, table A named = Authors, and table B named = Books.

In table A, I have a primary key called = au_id which, this table only holds the authors first and lastname and country.

Table B, has columns for book_id, published_date, genres, and an au_id (which I put the same number from table A's au_id.

Example,

`Authors` table

```
[au_id (Primary Key)],[au_fname],[au_lname],[City],[Country]
1, Robert, Jordan, Carolina, USA
```

`Books` table

```
[book_id(Primary Key)],[book_title],[genres],[publisher],[release_date],[au_id]
1, The Eye of the Storm, Fantasy, Tor Books, January 2004, 1
```

How can I create a query that can grab all the books by a certain author?

I tried to Google this question, but cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Do a search for `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE` clause.

Comment: While it would not make a difference in this particular case, whenever you ask a SQL question you should include what RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, ...) you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the tables on the `au_id` column:

```
select a.au_fname,
  a.au_lname,
  b.book_title
from books b
inner join authors a
  on b.au_id = a.au_id
where a.au_lname = 'lastname'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way of writing SQL query for the your problem.

```
select a.au_fname,
a.au_lname,
b.book_title
from books b,authors a
where b.au_id = a.au_id and a.au_lname = 'lastname'
```

For more details on SQL joins you can refer [joins here](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm).